# How can we integrate our rest api into shopify?

Tags: rest, shopify, shopify-template, shopify-api-node

For some additional features, i want to integrate our rest API in shopify?
suppose i have a rest API which i want to integrate into shopify liquid page.
I know this can be,but how can we do this?
can anyone explain? please help.

Answer (score 0):

For free, sign-up as a Shopify partner so you get access to making your own Apps. With that, you can make an App for your shop, and use the App Proxy to add your own API to Shopify.

https://help.shopify.com/en/api/guides/application-proxies

Comment: Is there any possibility without using shopify partners account?

Comment: No. Why would they let just anyone do anything? They at least need to know the account is human trying to do stuff.